# RESTful Rails 3 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes

I'm new to RESTful design and confused: if I make PUT, GET or POST to a same resource, say, /weblogs/myweblog, how should I write in the route.rb, and related controller?
Does the following works?
In route.rb

```
match 'weblogs/myweblog/new' => 'weblogs#create_new_blog'
match 'weblogs/myweblog/edit/:id' => 'weblogs#edit_blog' 
.
.
```

In weblogs_controller.rb

```
def create_new_blog
   ...
end

def edit_blog
  params[:id]..
  ....
end
```

and confused if I want to do GET/PUT/POST on the same resource, if their URL is same but only HTTP request is different, how to write different operations in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's best to define your routes in terms of resources, so if you have a resource named `webblog`, your routes can be defined using just:

```
resources :weblogs
```

If you check the routes generated by this (with `rake routes`), you will see that it defines a standard set of mappings from `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE` actions on urls to controller actions:

```
   webblogs GET    /weblogs(.:format)         weblogs#index
            POST   /weblogs(.:format)         weblogs#create
new_webblog GET    /weblogs/new(.:format)     weblogs#new
    webblog GET    /weblogs/:id(.:format)     weblogs#show
            PUT    /weblogs/:id(.:format)     weblogs#update
            DELETE /weblogs/:id(.:format)     weblogs#destroy
```

These routes will map to standard controller actions `index`, `create`, `new`, `show`, etc.

If for whatever reason you want to define routes *without* using `resources`, you can define them separately:

```
get '/weblogs' => 'weblogs#index'
get '/weblogs/new' => 'weblogs#new'
get '/weblogs/:id/edit' => 'weblogs#edit'
put '/weblogs/:id' => 'weblogs#update'
...
```

By defining routes with `get`, `put` etc. you can map a single URL to multiple controller actions, e.g. like this:

```
get '/weblogs/myweblog' => 'weblogs#show_myweblog'
put '/weblogs/myweblog' => 'weblogs#update_myweblog'
post '/weblogs/myweblog' => 'weblogs#create_myweblog'
destroy '/weblogs/myweblog' => 'weblogs#destroymy_weblog'
```

This will map the URL /weblogs/myweblog to the method `show_myweblog` for a GET request, `update_myweblog` for a PUT request, `create_myweblog` for a POST request, and `destroy_myweblog` for a DELETE request.

Alternatively, using the standard `resources`, you can pick and choose which routes you want from the full set with the `only` option:

```
resources :weblogs, only: [:show, :edit]
```

See the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more details. I hope this answers your question, if not please provide more details on what you want to do in the comments.